# Flex Slider not working when SSL added to domain

Tags: javascript, ssl, flexslider

I have a website that has been using FlexSlider successfully for many months now.

I am new to using SSL and I have just added an SSL certificate (Let's Encrypt) to the domain and it resolves correctly as https://, but the FlexSlider no longer works (i.e. The slideshow no longer appears on the page).

I have searched the net and this site but cannot find any clues as to what may be wrong. Given that i have not made any changes to the code, I am at a loss.

Is there something special that needs to be done to make FlexSlider work after adding SSL?

I do hope this is simple and someone can point me in the right direction.

Tany thanks

Tog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news! I found the answer on a different site, and as I thought, it was fairly simple.

The code included the following line:

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

which had to be changed to:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I hope this is useful to anyone else who has a similar problem.